# Should a winapi question be closed as a duplicate if it has been asked before in the context of a different programming language?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I used my dupehammer to close this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697228/how-to-prevent-users-from-closing-my-application

as a duplicate of this one:

[Prevent user process from being killed with "End Process" from Process Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185975/prevent-user-process-from-being-killed-with-end-process-from-process-explorer)

My judgement is that although one asks in a Delphi context, and the other a C++ context, the fundamental question is the same. The API calls needed are identical. My view is that the question is language agnostic, just as the Windows API is language agnostic. The issue, in my opinion, relates to the API calls that are needed, and I would argue that implementing code to call those API functions is of secondary importance.

Another user subsequently wielded his dupehammer to reopen.

Was I wrong to close the question?

Comment: One wrinkle that should probably be noted; the user who wielded the dupehammer to reopen has an answer on the question. Not exactly a neutral third party.

Comment: @Mike I didn't really want to get into that. Nor the fact that this user's answer is 100% language agnostic. That's all a different matter. I'm more interested in whether or not it is reasonable to view such questions as being language agnostic.

Comment: Thanks to the meta effect an answer quoting a Raymond Chen blog (a recipe for success anyway) now gained twelve upvotes on basically a _"you shouldn't be doing this"_ answer. :/ Worse even, that answer could just as well have been posted under the duplicate.

Comment: If you can remove all the specifics of both questions (delphi and c++ stuff) while keeping the same question intact, and they describe the same issue, then yes.

Comment: One thing I'm concerned about, doesn't this imply that things in the `System.Drawing` namespace for C# should be closed as dupes of GDI+ C++ questions? In my opinion this would be confusing because the C# resources have `IDisposable`, this might result in people copy/pasting C++ examples not knowing they could/should wrap them in `using` when they are used in C#.

Comment: Why do people do not want the user of this site to have their query answered , people with high reputation think they own everything.

Comment: @SurajJain Closing as a duplicate does answer the question and is very often helpful and constructive: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: @Suraj why do people think this site exists to answer their every programming question on demand? People with low reputation think this site exists to give them help specifically tailored to them, so they don't even have to try to understand what they are doing.

Comment: @CodeCaster http://stackoverflow.com/users/44330/jason-s Even he agrees. https://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/741.php

Comment: @Suraj please either comment under the question or under an answer with the same comments, not both. Anyway yes, there are plenty of blogs out there where people whine about how Stack Overflow works. That doesn't make Stack Overflow a bad site, nor does it mean its users "think they own everything". It just means that you and those bloggers have the wrong expectations of this site. Your complaints also have no relation whatsoever to this question, so please stop it - or ask your own question, after having read [ask].

Comment: And the question is gone...

Comment: The title, about "should a winapi question", is an unwarranted generalization. The Windows API is not language-agnostic. For example, using a [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx) is trivial from a scripting language and horribly complicated from C++, because it's a part of the API designed to support scripting. And for example, large parts of the C++ binding to the GDI+ API is in the form of C++ header files (C++ source code, not a binary API), that I believe has no equivalent in a language like Delphi. But the question at hand was a dupe, yes.

Comment: I commented on this, and my comment appears to have been removed. I see someone has also gone to my profile, gone to all my questions, and downvoted them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say it's fine.

A .NET question, where C# is used to illustrate the question, can also be answered using VB.NET or F# code, as long as the type and method names are recognizable.

The same applies here. It doesn't matter how you write this pseudo-code:

```
var find = FindFirstFile(dir, &findData);

do
{   
    HandleFile(findData);

} while (FindNextFile(dir, &findData))
```

It's clear that you're supposed to call `FindFirstFile()` first and `FindNextFile()` after that until it returns a falsey value in order to find all files in a directory.

It shouldn't matter in the slightest whether that code sample is given in C, C++, C#, Delphi or in any kind of pseudocode: its intentions are very clear, and who needs to initialize what and pass which variable in what way is something for the implementor to look up in the documentation anyway.

So yes, API questions can be closed as a duplicate of a question where the exact same problem, but in another (yet commonly used) language is being discussed.

---

Look, the problem I have with duplication is that usually the code is spread around, but not the explanation. For the Windows API, there is for example the common question *"How can I drag a borderless window?"*. The simple answer to that is simple: *"Let your entire window act as the title bar, by responding with `HTCAPTION` to a `WM_NCHITTEST` message"*. And that answer is copy-pasted around *a lot* - and is language-agnostic.

What this copy-pasted answer *doesn't* tell you, is for example that now wherever you drag the mouse on your window, drags that window around. So you may want to inspect the X and Y parameter of the hittest message to designate a certain area of your window as draggable.

A decent answer explains this, and even if it is accompanied by C++ code, the logic explained therein can be applied to any programming language.

Of course it is a different story altogether when a framework provides a wrapper. Setting .NET's WinForms `Control.Text` to a string is not comparable at all to calling `SetWindowText()` - **unless** the question is about an API-specific part of setting a control's text that applies to both approaches equally.

So to be thorough, if you don't agree with the above, you'd need to copy the entire accepted answer of the non-duplicate, and replace all `->` with `.` or `::`, or vice versa. What are we doing then?

Comment: I don't agree. Say you only know Haskell, you wouldn't recognize the syntax of C# and you wouldn't able to easily understand the answer. There's enough subtlety to it. Even if the answer was written out in the exact same coding style as the docs, it wouldn't be as easily understood to a Haskeller.

Comment: @Tankor Isn't that just part of the life of a functional programmer that does systems programming? Surely you must learn how to read C++. Otherwise how can you do anything. MSDN doesn't have a Haskell translation. I can see that it's perhaps harder for the Haskell programmer but conceptually isn't it just the same?

Comment: @Tankor in my opinion every programmer should be able to read C-like languages, just as they should be able to read a bit of English. If a Haskeller doesn't speak C and wants to call the WinAPI, then their question becomes _"I found this C code, how to translate it to Haskell?"_, and the WinAPI-specific part of the question disappears.

Comment: @CodeCaster this is just pulling apart examples, but I mean like how is that different from 'here's how you split a string in Java, how do you split it in Python'? Asking how to split a string in Python is different than in Java, even though the end result is the same (a split string).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm only speaking from personal experience, but when I was starting out, and people were linking the Windows docs on how to use their API, I would have much rather had 'heres the python calls to make' rather than 'heres the name of the functions in C'. It's pretty close to only knowing the basics, but I lean towards helping.  I think that the MSDN is so strictly tied to the format it is is a weakness, but that's a different issue.

Comment: @Tankor The Java vs Python split example is different because they are part of the runtime for each language. Two different libraries. But here we are talking about one single library, Win32. I feel that's the key point.

Comment: @Tankor Speaking to your experience as a novice doing Win32 in Python I think there's no shortcut. I think you have to learn enough C++ to read MSDN. If you can't read the documentation and you rely on third party articles with code in Python, say, you will make mistakes. Because those articles will contain inaccuracies and omissions. My personal experience is that my ability to write good interop code improved enormously when I decided to become more proficient in C++ (my main daily work is Delphi).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understand where you're coming from in that it's the same underlying libraries, but the syntax and functions you call aren't named exactly the same. It feels very comparable to splitting a string. I'm happy to disagree though, I think I understand you very clearly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't subscribe to the ideas that third party docs are necessarily worse that first party. But we'll have to disagree that it's necessary to know C++. It certainly helps but I don't think it should be necessary for a one off function call. Obviously if you're doing heavy OS integration you'll want to cover your bases, but if you're looking to minimize a window or something, you don't need to learn the entire language if a three line Python answer would do you just as good.

Comment: @Tankor Even a one off function call is seldom just that. Call ShowWindow to minimise a window? Where do you get the window handle from EnumWindows? FindWindowEx? Add it all up and there's invariably complexity. Here in SO every single day we see many questions where people have copied poor code from third party site with no or erroneous error checking. With incorrect buffer length handling. Broken string encodings. And so on. To use any library correctly you need to read the documentation, even more so for a C style API like Win32.

Comment: Similar situations have been discussed in the context of Objective-C/Swift, and AFAIR the consensus has been that questions that are purely about the APIs can be answered in either language if they are new (although one should prefer the language the OP indicated), and can be closed as duplicates of questions using either language (possibly by adding an answer to the dupe target in the other language if there isn't already one, or editing the translation into one of the answers).

Comment: @JörgWMittag I definitively don't want my Swift API questions to be answered in Objective-C.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar So you'd ignore an existing question that gave the answer you needed in Obj-C?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: We are not talking about Swift questions here. We are talking about API questions. E.g. a question about how to use the Qt API will have exactly the same answer regardless of whether you are using Swift, Objective-C, Objective-C++, C, C++, Python, Ruby, Perl, or Modula-" to access it. Questions about Swift, and about Swift APIs such as `Optional` clearly shouldn't be answered in anything but Swift.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I didn't mean Swift API as language, but iOS API in context of Swift.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If I find existing question with answer in Objective-C, I would try to use that answer to solve my issue. But if I ask question marked with Swift, I certainly don't want answers in Objective-C or getting closed as Obj-C duplicate. Again, just because I might be able to scrape some useful information out of other language answer does not mean everyone does.

Comment: @Dalija _"scrape some useful information out of other language answer"_ really makes it sound as if that is hard. If you have basic programming abilities, and your question is _"In UI framework X, which API call do I need to set the color of a text label?"_, then you should be able to continue working with an answer in whichever commonly used programming language, as long as it is (made) clear which part of the code addresses the API specifically. If not, you have other problems.

Comment: I'd argue that if somebody can't get the information they need from a winapi question with C++ example code, then they won't get it from one with Delphi code either. Certainly for this question that's the case. Short of a remote session to write the asker's entire program, nothing we could have done would have solved his problems. Again, I would argue that if you can't read C++ winapi code then you have no business expecting to succeed in writing winapi code in any other language

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Close it as broad. I didn't say it was great question. What I am saying is that I don't like practice of closing questions as another language duplicates.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yeah, people have other problems. There is very little content on SO that you can say that covers issues that are really hard to solve even after you have read all the documentation and searched the Internet. And is still plenty of content on SO that we could say it is very valuable even though it covers some either basic or less complex issues.

Comment: @Dalija I think by now I have made my case why I don't like duplication, especially in the context of complex APIs such as the Windows API. There are already enough copy-paste programmers in the world and copy-paste answerers on Stack Overflow. If you can't translate `[FooLib::BarMethod SomeParam SomeOtherParam]` to `FooLib->BarMethod(someParam, someOtherParam)`, then you're not going to be really **helped** by a copy-pasted answer where the code in the former language has been translated to the latter.

Comment: Well, Stack Overflow should be nuked altogether because most of its content is all about copy-paste programming.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar oh, I wholeheartedly agree, but that's another discussion, for another day.

Comment: Only the rubbish should be nuked. Which these days is the majority. Sadly. Oh for the good old times before the summer of love.

Comment: One simple example where translation can seriously go wrong. In C++ `pchar` is pointer to 8-bit char, in Delphi since version 2009 `pchar` is pointer to 16-bit char. In Delphi `string` is used for manipulating strings and `pchar` is rarely used besides WinAPI interaction. Translating C++ code with `pchar` can easily end up in disaster. And you don't have exactly to be newbie to make this kind of error.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar if you're passing the wrong kind of strings around, you're going to have a very specific, observable, programming language-related question. Again, this Meta question deals with very generic API usage, which is **programming language-agnostic**.

Comment: @CodeCaster It is language agnostic to the point you have to call this API to do the job. How exactly code calling that API should look like is not language agnostic. Linked question also has answers with C++ code. Also we are talking not just about this particular question, but general practice. I am saying it is easy to translate code in wrong way. You may not even know you have created potential problem in your code. It may run fine but have deeper implications.

Comment: @Dalija in those scenarios it doesn't matter what language is used, the poor programmer will get it wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What I am saying is that you don't have to be extremely poor programmer to get it wrong. There were wrong WinAPI calls in Delphi sitting in RTL till XE5.

Comment: @dalija and what I am saying is that an example written in Delphi rather than c++ will make no difference to that. But furthermore, that is all irrelevant. Is the language relevant to the crux of the question. Yes or no. That's what matters. If some user can't write correct code in their own language, that is their problem.

Answer (score 5):

> Should a question with irrelevant context be closed as a duplicate if it has been asked before in another irrelevant context?

The answer to that is another question: are all answers to the former equally fully valid to the later if we remove the irrelevant context? If yes, then I suggest you to remove the irrelevant context from *both* questions and close as duplicated. Two questions are duplicates when they are basically asking the same thing. Sometimes you need more context to know, other times, you need less.

If you can't do this without changing the questions in a meaningful way (invalid answers becomes valid or vise-versa), just create answers for both of them, tailored to the specific needs.

Comment: ["It isn't a duplicate because it wasn't good enough for me"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41731323). A statement so awesome, I'm considering adding it to my profile.

Comment: @RadLexus O_O??

Comment: Just read that comment thread there :) It's awesome in its pure flat denial of duplicateness. (I dearly wish I had bookmarked one saying "but my variables have other names!")

Answer (score -2):

If I am looking for an answer to a C++ question, I certainly dont want to read
a Delphi question, and vice versa.

I certainly would not want my C++ question closed as a duplicate of a Delphi
question, that just seems like madness.

It would be one thing for C <-> C++, but come on man. Reading the comments here
it seems like you would be inclined to tell the user "just learn C++" or
similar. This is not constructive, and not helpful.

If the original question was language agnostic, or you want to go through the
old question and all the answers and make it that way, then do that and **then**
use the dupehammer. I feel in the context the onus is on you to close a question
when appropriate. This situation just feels like someone itching to use a
dupehammer without putting in the work.

Comment: In this case the argument is that the question is language agnostic and is in fact a winapi question

Comment: Why do you think it would be reasonable to close C questions as duplicates of C++ questions, but not Delphi questions as duplicates of C++ questions? This seems quite curious to me.

Answer (score -3):

If answering the question does not require code then it is fine to close it. But in any other way no.

C++ is not Delphi and translating even simple API calls from C++ to Delphi side may be hard job for some people.

I would not close it as duplicate, even though Delphi answer provided does not have any code. Someone might come by and provide some relevant Delphi code. If questions is closed he cannot and posting Delphi code under C++ duplicate would not go well.

---

Or in another words. If the only thing wrong with the question is that it is API question that already has answer in another language tag then it should not be closed as duplicate.

If it is bad question, and dupehammer is just a way of closing bad question quickly even if dupe target is not "perfect" then I would say go with it.

---

**Why closing good API/frameworks as dupes in another languages is bad.**

While API is the same languages are different. That should be sufficent reason enough. People asking question and tagging it with specific language tag don't have to be familiar with other language.

Understanding API and explanation about API is one thing, understanding code written in different language is another.

SO allows beginner questions if they are good enough. Learning coding is hard enough when you are fresh. Should we force people learning their first language to learn another too?

Closing such questions as dupes, we are not only doing that to OP, but to other developers that might find anser in particular language useful. We are also forcing them to use language they might not know.

In this case it is about closing Delphi question as C++ dupe. What if first question asked would be Delphi one. How would you feel that C++ question about some API gets closed as Delphi dupe. Or Fortran. Or any other language capable of interacting with said API.

What if non C++ dev can provide better answer than the ones posted in C++ question. If Delphi question gets closed he cannot do that. Would it be acceptable to post Delphi code with API explanation under C++ tag. Would it be acceptable to post Fortran code there.

Would it be acceptable for Delphi question about FireMonkey API to be answered with C++ Builder code or closed as C++ Builder dupe. I don't think so.

Android SDK API uses Java. There are tools offering Pascal, Swift and C# variants. Would it be acceptable to use any of those for answering any Android API question?

Providing code opens up doors to copy-paste programming. Providing any code does. How do you know C++ beginner would not take C++ code and use it without understanding. It is not our job to tell people how should they use materials they find here. It is their responsibility.

We ask people to understand code they will use instead of just copy pasting it. How can they understand code in language they don't understand. Even if you do transtale code by yourself you can make subtle errors with translation. Translating does not imply understanding.

With this kind of practice we are discriminating developers from languages that are not primary for any given API.

Commenting or adding link to the other question in your own elaborate answer, pointing to additional read in another question would be fine. Closing question would not.

Making this kind of dupe closing proper practice we open up doors to total mess.

Comment: _"may be hard job for some people"_ - then they need help tranlating code, not calling an API.

Comment: @CodeCaster Translating code questions are rarely well received. Also, if closed as duplicate there may be numerous Delphi users that would have to go through same translation issue. C++ And Delphi are different enough having two questions that cover same API calls is fine.

Comment: @CodeCaster The other day I stumbled upon Delphi question about parsing JSON and someone wrote JavaScript code for it. Seriously. And you can argue that this would be fine too, because both are about JSON.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Of course translation questions are not well received. Stack Overflow isn't here to do the translation, and that's how they tend to be asked. I think it is naive to imagine that is possible to code against winapi without being able to read and understand C++. All the documentation is written that way. All the examples are for C++. Attempting to code against an API like Win32 without reading the documentation is folly. So it's reasonable, in my view, for winapi questions to require a certain level of competence.

Comment: No, the case here is very clear: a public API. This applies to the Windows API, but also for example libraries as iText. The method calls are the same, the number and types of parameters are the same no matter the language used to call the API. I'd even go as far as claiming the same applies to web services, who just require the same HTTP calls. Of course you can't apply JavaScript JSON parsing code to Delphi, because those are entirely different APIs.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar No. That's two different JSON libraries.

Comment: This is Stack Overflow, not MS documentation, if the question itself is fine and there is code involved you should not assume OP understands C++ to the point he does not care about answer language. Specific language competence is not required to ask questions on SO. If OP marks question about WinAPI with two language tags then answering in either one would be fine.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yeah, I was stretching that JSON example out of proportion.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar A prerequisite for using winapi is the ability to read its documentation. It's pointless to pretend otherwise. Helping people code in the face of ignorance. What is the point of that?

Comment: Reading the documentation is one thing, ability to turn that into a code is something completely different. I can fully understand Windows API documentation in terms what specific API does. Translating C++ samples to Delphi... well, that part does not always go smoothly... and I am not a beginner... but C++ is just not my turf.

Comment: As @CodeCaster says, then that is a different issue altogether

Comment: _"If the only thing wrong with the question is that it is API question that already has answer in another language tag then it should not be closed as duplicate"_ - explain _why_ you think so. Your only motivation seems to be _"translating even simple API calls from C++ to Delphi side may be hard job for some people"_, which is not very compelling.

Comment: @CodeCaster I updated the answer with more elaborate explanation.